# How to add relational data to DataStore with AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, expo, aws-amplify

Im very new to aws in general and Im trying to use amplify as a backend solution for my expo/react native app. I am trying to model the my data below into amplify. My data:

`DayMeals`

```
interface DayMeals {
    date: string,
    calories: number,
    proteins: number,
    carbohydrates: number, 
    fats: number, 
    items: Item[]
}
```

where `Item` is typed as

```
interface Item {
    image: string,
    name: string, 
    id: string,
    calories: number,
    proteins: number,
    carbohydrates: number, 
    fats: number, 
}
```

Currently, my schema defined in the GraphQL (through amplify studio) looks like :

```
type DayMeals @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  Items: [Item] @hasMany(indexName: "byDayMeals", fields: ["id"])
  date: String
}

type Item @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  image: String
  name: String
  calories: Int
  proteins: Int
  carbohydrates: Int
  fats: Int
  daymealsID: ID! @index(name: "byDayMeals")`
}
```

Assuming its defined correctly in the schema, I want to add meals to specific days. How can I do so? I assume I need to create `DayMeals` first, and then add `Items` to `DayMeals.Items`. Im stuck with creating Daymeals.

```
await DataStore.save(
    new DayMeals({
        "Items": [],
        "date": "01_30_2023"
    })
);
```

I get a error message of "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'ID' within parent 'Item' (/syncItems/items[0]/daymealsID)"

I believe my CLI is setup correctly as everything was working find if I am just creating `Item` without its relation to `DayMeals`

Comment: Wouldn't an item be related to multiple DayMeals?

Comment: im assuming no? I intend for DayMeals to contain all items/food entered for that day

Comment: The way you have defined it above, a given item (say "Spaghetti with meatballs") can only be served in a single DayMeal. Doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

#### `DayMeals` Model

`id: ID!` should be non-null value.

#### `Item` Model

`id: ID!` should be non-null value.

`daymealsID: ID!` should be non-null value.

### Solution

The error message mentions that the `daymealsID` field in the Item model is not being set, and that this is causing a problem because `daymealsID` is a non-nullable field (i.e. it cannot be null or empty).

```
// Create a new DayMeals object and set the date field
const dayMeals = new DayMeals({
  date: "01_30_2023",
  items: [],
});

// Create a new Item object and set the daymealsID field
const item = new Item({
  image: "...",
  name: "...",
  id: "...",
  calories: 0,
  proteins: 0,
  carbohydrates: 0,
  fats: 0,
  daymealsID: dayMeals.id,
});

// Add the Item object to the DayMeals object
dayMeals.items.push(item);

// Save the DayMeals object to DataStore
await DataStore.save(dayMeals);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! but now i encountered another error when pushing to items array. `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'AsyncCollection<LazyItem>'`

Comment: I have a `models/index.d.ts` file that was auto generated when i run `amplify pull` Im not familiar with it but it looks like all the properties are readonly

Comment: @benwl I am also stuck in the same issue. Were you able to resolve it? Please share your solution. I am trying to save a parent along with children.

Comment: no i was not. i pivoted away from datastore into using gateway with rest api to query dynamodb